# Please add the ability to email questions and answers to friends

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email, share-this

A friend and I were discussing the MVP vs. MVC pattern the other day (mainly in terms of "we don't know what MVP is and how it differs from MVC) and i found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) on SO discussing this.

Although I'm more than capable of opening an email client, pasting the link in, typing a subject and hitting send, I do think it would be nice to have an "email this to a friend" functionality like pretty much every news site on the Internet does. Maybe even a dead simple one like just typing in an email address, hitting send, and not even leaving the page.

Anyone else agree?

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways now to share questions:

- `share` link: clicking on this will open a text box with a shortened ([referral](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)) link to the question, which can easily be copied into an email
- SE 2.0 sites have links below the voting arrows to share on Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn
- All [unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74201/do-not-put-know-someone-who-can-answer-on-the-same-level-as-your-answer/74204#74204) questions have a banner below them which reads:

> **Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via [email], [twitter], [facebook], or [linkedin].**

The `via email` link opens a `mailto:` link with the email's body pre-populated with the question title and a (referral) link to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Meh. Copy what's in the address bar and paste in email. Not that big of a chore.

Answer (score 2):

This really falls under the "SO is not a social networking/news site". I see no need for the feature, especially when all that is required for you to do is to copy/paste the link.

Perhaps you can join the [greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) bandwagon and make this for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Every feature has a cost associated to developing it, even "simple" features. So there always has to be a value added or cost benefit analysis. With this feature, I'm just not sure the value added would be worth the development/maintenance costs and added clutter to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem like SO doesn't have a lot of standard tools that other sites have, but I think this is not necessarily a bad thing.  It gives SO a nice clean feeling.

Now I do agree I would like to see some of these tools available (see my [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/feature-request-spell-checker) for a spell checker), but I also would like SO to keep this clean look and feel.

Comment: I thought all the major browsers had spell check integrated by now.

Comment: Some don't.  I'm using firefox 3 right now, but its under Mandriva Linux and for some reason it doesn't work.  I mention in my article how you really can't count on people already having spell check access.

Comment: That sucks. I've started to take it for granted.