# Twitter integration

Tags: feature-request, twitter

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Tweet question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/tweet-question-and-answer)
>   [Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter)

I'd like to be able to have my SO questions tweeted to my Twitter account when I ask them, so anyone following me on T can go into SO and answer if they know the answer. I thought about creating a program that does this in some way, but it seems a natural place for such feature should be in SO itself. How would this work:

- each user would have a "twitter account" fields with username and login info
- once the user starts a new question on SO, the title and link to question gets posted to twitter

It could be also triggered when the user's answer is accepted or he earns a new badge.

Comment: Question on SO for developing such a script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311383/script-to-publish-my-so-qs-and-as-on-my-twitter

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/) to do this.  Just add your SO RSS feed.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that http://twitter.com/isnotrss

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the community fairly resistant to this sort of thing. See:

[Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter)

Or click on the [twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tag to see what I mean. I personally am agnostic about this kind of integration.