# Automatically posting question updates to a user's twitter/facebook/linkedin

Tags: feature-request, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Most of us have at least one social network account if not more and it would be nice to be tweeted about questions I ask automatically if I get answers (of course only if I check the right checkbox).
Is this possible to implement?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42816/twitter-integration

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a good idea. Linking a question is ok, since it bring people who are wanting to participate in answering. But given the number of answer, this would burden the system and the connections.

Maybe broadcasting the accepted answer could be interesting.

Notifications are already handled by the "StackExchange" drop-down overlay.