# Order Announcer, Booster, and Publicist posts when you reach a lower threshold

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, publicity-badges

Suppose I shared a link that was visited by 1,000 unique IP addresses, but I didn't have the announcer badge, so I got that one.
In the future, If I shared a link with 50 unique IP addresses hits, I won't get a new badge.

I propose that the second link is associated with the announcer badge, using the first for the Booster badge (and if I then share a link with 400 unique IP addresses hits, the first one would be used for the publicists badge)

It's no easy task to get 1000 unique hits for a link, and sometimes it could be a 1 time thing, it would be a shame to use the slot for the announcer badge.

Comment: Shouldn't you straight away get all three badges from that link with 1000 visits?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way @sth -- see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/sequence-behind-awarding-link-badges-announcer-booster-publicist/64794#64794)

Comment: This appears to be resolved by [the recent changes to the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve/118509#118509).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you propose is how I feel the functionality should behave, but the scheduled task that awards badges currently isn't flexible enough to swap a user's existing badge for another one - it just likes to award.

We don't have time right now to work on this, but when we introduce more tiered badges, we will definitely do some refactoring.

Answer (score 11):

Not entirely answering your question, but we did decide to relax the requirements for these badges:

- **Announcer** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by <s>50</s> 25 unique IP addresses in <s>2</s> 3 days
- **Booster** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by <s>400</s> 300 unique IP addresses in <s>3</s> 4 days
- **Publicist** - Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1,000 unique IP addresses in <s>4</s> 5 days

Comment: Do you store the actual IP address or a hashed version of it as [Internet Archive does](http://blog.archive.org/2013/10/25/reader-privacy-at-the-internet-archive/)? And for how long?