# When is the Publicist badge awarded?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, publicity-badges

I recently (28 hours ago) submitted one of StackOverflow's interesting questions to [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2179081) and [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/ff5i6/im_graduating_with_a_computer_science_degree_but/), where it was featured on the front page all day. I used the [personalized link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823571/280598) the site gave me using the "Link" link.

That resulted in somewhere around 30,000 views of the question in less than a day. Several thousand of them were before the question was eventually migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com, and some tens of thousands afterwards.

The [Publicist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) is awarded for referring 1000 unique IPs to a shared question. I haven't earned this badge on either SO or programmers.SE.

Is this a bug? Will I earn it on neither site since the question was moved? Or is this badge awarded by a process run less often than the other badge-awarding processes, and I haven't waited long enough?

**Edit**: jzd was right, I got the silver badge for that question. I managed to promote another question and quickly got the gold badge. I should be sending SOIS over 100,000 extra page views this month from several programming communities :)

Comment: I know with a couple of my badges I had to wait 48 hours for the cache to clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this:  [Sequence behind awarding link badges (Announcer, Booster, Publicist)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/sequence-behind-awarding-link-badges-announcer-booster-publicist)

You get the badges in order first: announcer, booster, then publicist.  Looks like you got booster for this question because you already had announcer.  (Even though you might have enough views for publicist.)

Comment: Other questions about how these badges work say that they are awarded when they occur, not after the time period has expired. That was the case for other badges for "X views in X days" I already earned. Only this one doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Actually just found something else, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that's what happened