# How it works Announcer, Booster and Publicist Badges?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, sharing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
>   [Sequence behind awarding link badges (Announcer, Booster, Publicist)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/sequence-behind-awarding-link-badges-announcer-booster-publicist)

Hello

As you know, for these bagdes;

```
Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days
Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days 
Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days
```

1. This sharing for only `E-Mail`, `Twitter` of `Facebook`? For example; i share a question in my `Friendfeed` account then visited by 25 uniques IP address in 3 days via my `Friendfeed` account, do i win `Announcer` badge?
2. Uniques IP addresses is total number of sharing? For example; i share a question with `E-Mail`, `Twitter` and `Facebook`. In 3 days, With `E-Mail` 8 IP addresses visited, with `Twitter` 10 IP addresses visited, with `Facebook` 7 IP addresses visited, do i win `Announcer` badge ? Or should be visited 25 unique IP addresses just using one services ?

Best Regards,

Soner

Comment: or may be related with - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/sequence-behind-awarding-link-badges-announcer-booster-publicist

Comment: I dunno, but could you please click on this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89070/how-it-works-announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/1228