# How to get the booster badge [revisited]?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get the booster badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/how-to-get-the-booster-badge)
>   [How do I “share” a link for the new badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges)

Here is the question that got closed BEFORE I had my answer:

[How to get the booster badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/how-to-get-the-booster-badge-closed)

The link to the similar question that was provided didn't help because when I click the Link hyperlink, the page just refreshes. No link with my ID is displayed.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Right click it, select "copy link address" (or equivalent in other browsers than chrome), and paste it wherever you like.