# How does one share a question?

Tags: support, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I “share” a link for the new badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges)

One must share questions on the Apple Stack Exchange site for this challenge.

http://thenewipadishere.com/

How does one share questions? I can't find the share button.

Comment: The "link" button below each post gives your a referral link. The site will occasionally show sharing options for various social networks, but they just pre-populate a message with that same link.

Comment: ...you have until Monday 4/2/2012 at 23:59. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It is on the right if you want to share directly in Google+, Facebook or Twitter, plus `link` button.

[image]