# Why doesn't Stack Overflow offer built-in spellchecking of new questions?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a spell checker to the markdown editor.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor)

Why has Stack Overflow no tool for the checking of spelling when creating a new question?

Comment: I think he is asking why doesnt spellcheck apply to the questions title box like it does in the description, comment box, answer etc.

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor

Comment: In chrome you can turn on the spell checking of text boxes, though it doesn't seem to remember the setting (as opposed to text areas where it's on all the time)

Comment: I don't want to have to use Greasemonkey to remove a script that I don't want either hogging my system nor fighting my browser of choice. Also, people here should know how to enable the builtin spellchecker on all current browsers.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say that it's not really needed in the SO code because the option is easily attainable through either native browser functionality or extensions / add-ins.

Answer (score 4):

Two big reasons:

1. As others have mentioned, this is already built into most browsers.  Site-specific spell checkers just tend to cause problems and clash with the browser's spell checker.
2. Programming questions are murder on spell checkers anyway, as there tend to be a lot of unrecognized words involved (variables and other identifiers).

Comment: +1 Good point on the spell checker vs. code battle.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because that's already built in in modern browser.

For instance: I use firefox spellchecker

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/421/capturadepantalla201001vr.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/421/capturadepantalla201001vr.png)

Comment: -1: Chrome is Better (Kidding)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Stack Overflow-specific problem.

You may want to install a spelling checker in your browser, if you want to perform a spell check before posting, e.g. with the [Firefox Plugin "SpellBound"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9207) (there are many others as well, supporting various languages).

Comment: You don't really need that add-on, since FF will spell-check the text in the body of the question being composed already, and if you want to spell-check the title, it's a right-click away...

Answer (score 0):

Because we'd rather have the developer devote time to SO problems that cannot be solved on the user side with either existing browsers or other tools most people who have difficulty with spelling or typing already use.