# Challenge Factor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, voting

I thought about a complementary voting system that could be put in place based on the challenge factor of a question.

### Challenge Factor

- It could allow users passing by to at
  least give their opinion on the
  difficulty of the question by voting
  for how challenging the question is.
- A user would be denied the
  possibility to vote for his/her own
  question just like reputation.
- At the same time, this could be an
  opportunity to make it possible to
  give a bigger reward to the person
  who has the right answer.
- There could be a certain minimum
  amount of votes needed in order for
  the reward to be granted.
- I believe it would be best that there
  be a minimum of 0 for the "challenge
  factor".
- There could be clearly defined rules
  for voting such as to not vote based
  on a user's ability to ask a
  question. After all, the site as
  members all over the world so it
  makes sense. There are also some
  moderators or high-rep users that can
  help with that too by editing the
  question.
- It would make it possible to sort the
  questions based on the challenge
  level.

Would this be a good idea or rather superfluous and redundant to have a complementary voting system?

**Please note that this is not to replace the current voting system. It would be a second voting system.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58340/broken-english-but-a-valid-question-still-the-community-would-downvote-it

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea. Then newbs like me can get to answer questions we can handle and let the more experienced users answer very difficult questions.

May I add that we should have a thing like the tag system where you can have ignored levels of difficulty and then interesting levels of difficulty?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you mean by an ignored and interesting level of difficulty?

Comment: You know how you have interesting tags and ignored tags for Stack Overflow? You could have a desired difficulty range and a ignored difficulty range (i.e. I want to see questions in the range 1 - 3 (out of 10 or something) in difficulty but I don't want to see questions in the range 7-10) . That's the best way I can explain it.

Comment: That would be a great idea! It would allow sorting questions based on the challenge of a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your proposal would be unnecessary. If the question is legitimately difficult, they also tend to be good questions, in which case they should earn upvotes regardless. If the question is difficult because it is poorly written, well, then that's not really the spirit of the site.

> At the same time, this could be an
>   opportunity to make it possible to
>   give a bigger reward to the person who
>   has the right answer.

Are you familiar with the [bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)? Granted, it is different from what you propose, but I think that's it's close enough that it would satisfy you.

Comment: I am aware of the bounty system but it involves giving one's own reputation in order to bring more users on the question while what I am proposing is rather geared towards the opinion of users. Also, we could clearly define rules for voting such as to not vote based on a user's ability to ask a question. After all, the site as members all over the world so it makes sense. There are also some moderators or high-rep users that can help with that too by editing the question.