# Enable spell check on title, search and tag input element

Tags: feature-request, design, editor, firefox, spelling

This is a repost of **[Spell-checking in question titles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1663/spell-checking-in-question-titles)** on Meta.Gaming, except that this post furnishes the necessary technical details for it to work.

All `input type="text"` elements, by default, do not have have spell check enabled on Firefox. This option can be turned on by the client by using the right click context menu and checking the 'Check Spelling' option.

With HTML5, there is now the [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/controlling_spell_checking_in_html_forms) attribute. [As of March 2009](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-spellchecking), only Firefox supports this. However, there is no harm in turning it on, and so it should be turned on, if only for the Firefox users out there, and as more and more browsers adopt this attribute, this should be fairly useful for users.

Comment: Actually on a closer look Chrome does do spell checking there -- it just doesn't check text that is already there. Try removing the 'f' and pressing space.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor

Comment: I use FF exclusively, and spell check has always been turned on by default...?

Comment: @JonSeigel: It is on in the body of the question, but not the *title*.

Comment: @Richard: That's why I said that question was related. I didn't vote to close, btw.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. [Building an entire spell-checking system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83690/site-specific-spellcheck) may not be such a good idea, but adding one little `spellcheck="true"` attribute which may prevent a lot of typos **is**.

**Post title:**


```
Without spellcheck                  With spellcheck
```


[image: Screenshot of the title without spellcheck="true"]            [image: Screenshot of the title with spellcheck="true"]

**Edit summary:**


```
Without spellcheck                  With spellcheck
```


[image: Screenshot of the edit summary without spellcheck="true"]              [image: Screenshot of the edit summary with spellcheck="true"]

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this. I get spelling corrections as I type in Chrome (current release, 9.0) on the ask page, with all default settings.

this is me being a very bad speller in the title field on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

[image]

Comment: badp mentioned in the chatroom that Chrome remembers your spell check settings for that particular `input` field, so if you turned it on manually before it would've remembered that.

Comment: @yi I never touch any settings in Chrome. I haven't turned it on. It's just.. on. So you might want to reconsider this request.

Comment: @yi yep, just reproduced on my home theater PC as well.  Never touched a single setting on it, ever.. bone stock. And I get spelling corrections as I type on the title field in Chrome.

Comment: Right, I suppose I'll pull the Chrome part from the question, though the statement is still true for Firefox users

Comment: For illustration, I've made a few [screenshots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149449/188498) of Firefox with spellcheck disabled and spellcheck manually enabled (via *Contextmenu > Check spelling*). See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149449/188498) to this question.