# How do I see favorite question notification

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks

About several months ago, I often received notices when my favorite question changes (answers added, question modified). But I no longer receive notification recently. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: You mean the envelope that turned yellow by any chance?

Comment: @Shadow: yes, I mean that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no true notification anymore: you will have to hover your username to see [the recent activity popup](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/). That lists the changes to favorites in the 3rd row.

Comment: thanks, but why StackOverflow drop the utility? I mean, it's nice to have a notification (yellow envelope) once a day.

Comment: I read the link, too bad there's no easy way to know favorite question

Comment: @Hoàng, you might like [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) then! (If it gets implemented.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also visit the favorites tab in your profile frequently, it's sorted by default by the last activity time so you'll see changes on top.

Comment: And: if that tab is not active, but still is decorated with an asterisk (*), then there are new changes since your last visit.

Comment: @Arjan yep. Maybe they can make the little arrow to the left of user name have background when there's a change? This will preserve the envelope functionality just fine. :)

Comment: ...that might get it to light up randomly like the old envelope did ;-) (Anyway, for favorites, see [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox).)

Comment: @Arjan randomly? Can't remember such thing... only when there was favorite change and the favorite question itself got deleted, the highlight was apparently without any reason. Thanks for the link! :)