# What does a small asterisk in the favorites tab in my user profile mean?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks, tabs

I have gone through [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), however I still do not know what does a small asterisk in the favorites tab header in my user profile mean?

i.e. the tab sometimes appears as `* favorites`:

[image: Asterisk next in the favorites tab]

Comment: That mean something has changed somewhere within your favorite posts.

Comment: And how do I know what is that something? like which of the favorite has the update and what exact part of it (the question, answer, comment)? Is there some (visual) cue?

Comment: Note that this [seems to be work in progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox).

Comment: BTW, if there can be a feature wherein the questions (that have changes) are colored slightly differently when user clicks on \*favorites tab and looks at favorited question list, it would be relatively easier.

Comment: @publicgk: Oh yes, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Should we then put a request for that feature? And how to do that? (Or if one of you can do it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mean something has changed somewhere within your favorite posts.

And this is what I do when I want to look that what it was changed.

- Click favorite tab with *

[image]

- Make sure it is sorted by recent (As you see, first question had some activity at 7h ago by Will, and second question had latest activity at 9h ago, third one had some actions at 9h ago too)

[image]

You can click those 7h ago, and 9h ago links to check what is those (those links has `?lastactivity` parameters just like the one in homepage)

- You can click 'x hours ago" button for revisions history to check what is changed to that post

[image]

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/88127/revisions

[image]

- If you want to check the evey changes to the whole thread, you can also check timeline by changing question revisions link to timeline at address bar in your browser.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/88127/timeline

[image]

Comment: Wow. Such a detailed explanation. And nice example. :) Thanks.

Comment: Not bad at all. The only thing I'm wondering about: If someone leaves a _comment_ on one of my favorite questions, this will give a favorite notification, but it won't count as recent activity in the "favorite" tab (if I'm not mistaken). How can I find that comment then?

Comment: @Hendrik, I favorited this post, and I don't have asterisk on my profile though. (we are now commenting right?)

Comment: But not on the _question_. EDIT: I've tried to notify you by adding a comment to the question.

Comment: @Hendrik, I have deleted my comments, and realized that you're right. I also don't know how can I find out comment changes on favorite tab.