# Why doesn't the Favourite Question option subscribe me to changes to the question?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, global-inbox, favorites-notifications

The way I see it, the favourite button should be like a mechanism for you to follow a question without actually answer or contributing to it.

So I think that whenever you hit Favourite on a question, if there are new answers, comments, etc., it should notify you in the Inbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

Answer (score 1):

You already *do* get notified of activity on questions that you've favorited. There's a tab for it in your profile that lights up with a number indicating the number of active posts. It's cleverly labeled "favorites", located right under the "Ask Question" button:

[image: "Favorites" tab in profile]

So, I don't really think we need more notifications cluttering up our inboxes...

Comment: oh ok. Yeah I guess it doesn't seem apparent which of the questions have changed. Also, you can't see them if you're logged into another SE site. I also just noticed the "notify <email> daily of any new answers". I could use that, although I think that would be quite annoying getting emailed all the time.