# Tracking which post has new response under favorites?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

The favorites tab shows "* with blue background" where someone post comments,answer or even accept answer. But when I navigate to that tab, it is hard to know which ones were updated.

The current behavior is kind of confusing because sometimes I do see some updates and sometimes I don't. And so I have to flip through couple of posts and then give up.

Do the posts that were updated move to the top of they stay where they are? If they move to the top, under specific cases or always?

**Edit:** I have set the sort order: "recent".

As what **Hendrik** said is the confusion. It is hard to find the post to which a comment was added. Many times I have to leave comment to question to get more clarifications. Then I mark that as favorites to track. Not all users reply/comment in @username format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sort order "recent" is The Way to Go; it shows your favourites with most recent activity at the top. However, only new *answers* count as activity. Thus, if someone left a *comment to the question*, you'll be notified of that update in the dropdown under your user name, but you'll have no hint *where* to find that comment. Thus the current behaviour is indeed somewhat confusing.

Comment: Yes,that's exactly the confusion.

Comment: @gbs: Then I've given you all the _support_ there is. Maybe what you really want is a _feature-request?_ Please also check this post: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343).

Answer (score 1):

You have many sort order at your disposition :

- votes
- newest
- views
- recent
- added

just choose whichever you want.

Comment: I have it selected as "recent", so if there is an alert it means at least the top post should have some activity right? But lot many times that is not the case and not even top 3.