# Optionally add responses to favorite questions to inbox notifications

Tags: feature-request, support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

This question is either a request for support to an existing feature I have not been able to find or a feature request if it does not yet exist.

I have selected quite a few old and largely inactive questions as "favorites."  Some of these questions occasionally get updated with new answers, edited answers or questions, or comments.  At the moment, the only way I know of to find out if there has been new activity is to visit my user page to check for the presence of a red asterisk near the favorites tab.  As far as I can tell, activity in the favorites does not bubble up to the level of my SE inbox.  I would like a user preference allowing me to opt in to receiving inbox notifications for my favorites.

Furthermore, if someone merely comments, I never receive any sort of notification.  I know people here have often remarked that comments are just that, and the Qs and As are the main content, but I would at least like an option to be notified of any sort of changes, including comments, on certain questions I care most about (hence, favorites).

Comment: Great idea - a "watched-questions" feature.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I suspected it might be a duplicate, and I searched and honestly could not find a relevant question.  Nevertheless, nothing seems to have come of that question and it's been a while.  Has this entered status-planned at all?

Comment: @Tal - we revisit it periodically, we've started leaning in the direction of re-working favorites into "following".  No timeline yet, and we're not 100% on it either.