# Allow me to subscribe a question to receive push notification in global inbox

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications, subscription

When I find an interesting question, I have two options:

1. Star it. But, to check updates, I need to visit the questions time-to-time. Its not push type.
2. Subscribe its feed. But, its also not push type. And, its not universal. If I switch to mobile devices for example, it becomes difficult. Tracking feeds is also bad experience (Google Reader kill advocates it).

Please, add a feature to subscribe a question and get notification of answers and comments on it in global inbox. To clear the clutter, you can automatically erase a subscribed question from list after 7 days.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) will serve your goal just fine if implemented.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd No. It'll crowd global inbox. We favorite questions just like bookmarking. So, notifications from favorites would be bad. And, to stop notification, we'd need to un-favorite a question which is again bad.

Comment: So what exactly are you suggesting? Push it where?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Optional subscriptions can't make global inbox crowded. I like to keep subscription & favorite separate so that I could un-subscribe a question without any problem.

Comment: What you ask is too "localized" in my opinion to get any real attention from the team. If you have Chrome, check [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hcamnijgggppihioleoenjmlnakejdph) out. (RSS Live Links browser extension)

Answer (score 6):

Have you noticed the question feed link on the bottom of each question?

[image: question feed link]

It's a little hard to notice, but it's on every question, and you can use any Atom-enabled service to be kept up to date on questions you want to see new activity on.

Comment: You can also get an RSS feed on user activity from their profile.

Comment: @CasperOne Yes, I know about that. Its no different than checking it from favorites. Its not push type.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Your request was not for something push-based, it was "So, it'd be better if I could subscribe a question and get notification of answers and comments on it. Please, add this feature with unsubscribe option." - Atom, while requiring polling, fulfills this request for you.

Comment: @CasperOne While It was understood thing as I praised global inbox over favorite, but I have added them in question. Thanks..