# Button to be alerted when a post is answered

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

I'm not sure if this feature exists, if it has I haven't been able to find it.

There are many times I come across a post on Stack Overflow that I really find interesting and would really like to know the outcome of, though it's not my post. Is there or could there be a button to mark the post such that a message is sent to my inbox that the question has been answered, when an answer to that question has been accepted or a bounty awarded?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can see the similarity, but my proposal isn't to subscribe to EVERY update to the question, that would be utterly annoying! Simply ONE message when an answer has been accepted as the solution.

Comment: So add this as comment or answer on the other question, it's only a tweak of that other same idea.

Comment: This is not a dupe.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have added this as a comment to the other post as you suggested, however I feel that the suggestion won't get the proper attention that it deserves by the community due to it being a small comment way down on the list of a very large article to which most people have already viewed and have agreed that it would be a bad thing, but that of which they do not want is to have their inboxes flooded with notifications, I wouldn't either. But this is where my suggestion is fundamentally different. Only receiving ONE notification per question and only when reached THE solution.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Therefore I feel that this was closed pre-maturely as the suggestion is not an "exact duplicate" as the reason for closing states. My post IS very similar, but I feel is fundamentally different enough to warrant a separate look at by the community to see how they feel about this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, still think that posting your idea there is more appropriate. If you want to give it more weight post it as new answer, there are more than a few already suggesting various ideas.