# Inbox notification when a favourite question has new activity

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

I rarely visit my own profile to look at favourite questions with new activity. I'd like to have inbox notifications for this.

Apparently [it was once added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications/57550#57550), but later removed again.

> [image: screenshot of deleted answer]

Can this be reimplemented? If not, why was it removed?

Comment: Oh, now I remember. Once upon a time, there was an envelope. whenever there was new inbox item or favorite change, it would turn red, maybe with a number. That old feature request asked to **disable** this as users got annoyed their envelope is changing so much. With the demise of the envelope, that feature request became irrelevant.

Comment: Another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the second one is a better duplicate. (Unfortunately I had already voted on the first duplicate.)

Comment: You can vote to close your own question then, as the second, then it will also appear in the list when closed.

Comment: I don't agree this would be a blanket good thing, it would be incredibly spammy depending on your favorites count. The way some people use favorites would make the inbox signal-to-noise ratio hit the floor.

Comment: @NickCraver the first implementation was opt-out as I understand, and one of the duplicates suggests an opt-in for this. Making it mandatory for everyone wouldn't be good indeed.