# Is there a way to notify all people who commented on a post at once?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I posted this question on Stack Overflow:
[What could make dynamic_cast start throwing std:bad_cast even if invoked on pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843937/what-could-make-dynamic-cast-start-throwing-stdbad-cast-even-if-invoked-on-poin)

I discussed with four people in the comments about different approaches that could help me fix the problem.

When I fix the problem (hopefully soon), I'll probably answer the question myself. But those four people won't get any notification in their Inbox that the question was answered. However it may may interest them as they showed some interest in the question.

So how can I make them all get a notification in their global-inbox? The only way I see is to add the same comment four times ("Hey look, I found what the problem was, see my answer") each one prefixed by a @replies tag targeting each participant.

Is there an easier/better way to do this, to have all participants be aware that a question was posted? a "@all" tag?

Had the same remark in the past from the other side of the mirror: commented and discussed with a guy and got no notifcation when the question finally got answered, even if I would have liked to because the topic interested me.

Comment: If they were really interessted in a solution, then they would track your question anyway (for example with marking it as "favorite"), so there so no need to ping them.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246687/notify-commentators-when-post-edited

Comment: @Tom If a favorited question is bumped, you don't get a ping about it. The order on your favorites changes on your profil, if you ordered it by activity. I roughly 2 years ago used this functionality last time.

Comment: @peterh **"If a favorited question is bumped, you don't get a ping about it"** - I haven't said one would get pinged.

Comment: @Tom Right. I only wanted to explain, that it requires the activity of the target persons to get the request, they don't get a feedback passively. Even to get the request, the have to do something which is likely not a very common thing on the SE - the majority of the questions isn't favorized by anyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, pinging everyone who has commented on your post would be poor form, unless they had specifically shown an interest in wanting to see the answer themselves.

Many users on Stack Exchange sites help out lots of people, and leave many comments for various reasons such as to ask for clarification or post other relevant information. These users might not actually need the solution to your problem in particular—they're just there to help and offer what they can to point you in the right direction. Therefore, pinging everyone who's commented just in case they might be interested in the answer is unwise.

Having an `@all` ping would, unfortunately, be open to abuse by users who want as much attention as they can for their post. Instead, if you're interested in the post and want to be notified when there are updates, you can [mark the question as a favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/336144). This will highlight the question in your favourites tab when there is any activity. You could have used that in your situation when you *were* interested in the answer to a question, but it's very much an **opt-in** thing; users shouldn't be getting notifications unless they're relevant and have already been asked for.

An `@all` ping is likely to just give notifications that are "noisy" and not wanted. For users that are commenting on many posts a day, I'm sure you can imagine how impractical it would be when they're getting dozens of additional pings *just in case* they're interested.

Comment: Let's say I comment on a post that interested me, I may come back to see it in the coming days. However, if it's still not answered by then, I'll most likely stop looking at it. And if it gets answered later, I'll never know (I never go to my "favorite" tab, I only check my inbox daily). I'd like a way for the system no notify me (via by global inbox) whenever this post gets a new answer or an edit, or a new comment, or whatever activity....that would be nice. Would it make sens to request a new feature, something similar to "favorite" but targetting your inbox rather than the favorite tab?

Comment: @jpo38 Apparently, [favourites did work like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237036/336144) originally, but it was changed to no longer give notifications because it was too noisy and annoyed many users. Given that, I'm not sure whether inbox notifications for favourites are likely in the future.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Most likely doing a feature request would not end up with this being reimplemented...

Comment: Besides, `@all` would cause problems if [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858508/all) commented.