# Prompt IE users to install IESpell when they first use the Markdown editor?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor, spelling

I read the following link, but for IE users the solution was a bit self serve and not explicitly documented as a step to follow that I have seen: [Please add a spell checker to the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor)

On the ASP.NET forums site [here](http://forums.asp.net/) the site automatically prompts the user to install 'iespell' upon 1st use if it has not been done already and integrates with their editor. The ASP.NET forums are not a sponsor of this product, but it would be nice for those of us that use IE to have this integrated here as well.

And probably most **importantly** here on this topic, I *have* IESpell installed but it does *not* show up integrated in the SO WYSIWYG editor.

Would it be possible to have a integrated spell check option for us IE users as I have suggested? It sure would be nice, but I understand the IE haters do not care so much for these requests as Chrome, FF, Safari, etc, are so prevelant.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply promotion of iespell?

Comment: If you think iespell should be working in the editor but it isn't, I would file that as a separate feature request (not really a bug as iespell isn't base browser behavior.)

Comment: I guess I was pretty nieve when I said Thanks *for listening*. The meta forums are like a cult of a few dominitaing the topics of conversation and playing Forum God. Many of you have forgotten what being a *true* community member and leader means. Go ahead and downvote to your hearts content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand the IE haters do not care so much for these requests as Chrome, FF, Safari, etc, are so prevelant.

Not really that we don't care for the requests as such; it's just...

Well, shoot. Other browsers have had spell-checkers for *years* now. I remember when add-ons like IESpell were really handy little tools, part of everyone's "install immediately upon getting a new machine" toolbox. But I also remember TSR calculator apps for DOS. Actually, DOS is a good analogy here: not much of an OS as far as high-level services went, so most apps shipped with a fair bit of code to handle non-essential stuff like "printing" and "making stuff appear on the screen" and "accessing RAM". Modern operating systems generally build that in...

...And modern *browsers* have spell-checkers. If you wanna use DOS, go ahead... but don't expect anyone to go out of their way to make that easier for you.

Comment: You are so caught up in your beliefs you don't even have the ability to look at views from a neutral perspective. Your 59k and 14 gold have gone to your head. "Modern Browsers?". To deny IE as having a considerable marketshare is denial of facts. You would never get my vote as a moderator with those narrow minded views. "Self-Absorbed" is a pretty good bio.

Comment: I didn't say *anything* about marketshare. Look... 7 years ago, in-browser spell-checking was a somewhat-exotic feature, and many web-apps did go to great lengths to provide spell-checking; now, it's not, and most don't. If you want a spell-checker and your browser of choice doesn't offer it, give its authors crap for that - heck, it's not like MS doesn't have access to one of the finest spell-checkers around. (as for the moderator jazz... Heh, nine people disliked your suggestion; maybe you need to do a better job of justifying the need rather than whining about the reception. )