# Spellchecker / grammar checker

Tags: feature-request, spelling, grammar

There seems to be a fair few questions and answers on SE sites with simple spelling or grammar mistakes in them, and as I am the sort of person who cares about such things, I used to spend the time going in and fixing these simple mistakes. Did, that is, until I realised how many of my edits were being rejected as being "insufficient edits".

It was shortly after that I noticed the `Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.` note. My bad :(

However, as this is still a passion for me, just now wondered why such a great(!) collection of sites doesn't yet have some softly, but actively, enforced automatic spelling and grammar checking/notification code, akin to (for example) Microsoft Word.

Could be something like / have handy additional features like:

1. A warning you have to click through if spelling / grammar mistakes are found in the post (Perhaps with a point penalty for mistakes, to encourage quality postings)
2. Simple spelling errors are corrected ad-hoc
3. The ability to set ones account to highlight the changes then approve sans input from the user after ¿5? seconds
4. Ability to add words to a global dictionary, which would be vetted like edits are

What does the community think?

**NOTE:** British English used in the question, and errors are excepted :)

Comment: For those who downvote this question, would request that some of you provide their reasons for doing so; Cool if you don't agree, but would be more constructive to answer why. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There really is no need for all the bold you have introduced in your last edit. The list of points was clear enough before it.

Comment: @user66001: We usually do read the comments when reviewing reopen votes, so just adding that as a comment is enough.

Comment: In this case, I am voting to leave it closed as a dupe. You can add your ideas as a separate answer to the other question, perhaps.

Comment: This question is not the same as what it was closed as a duplicate of. The other question simply asks for a spell checker (A job that as [NullPointer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176320) quite rightly points out is a capacity of many newer browsers). I was asking for functionality that would encourage users to accept automatic spell checking suggestions, so (in my case) there would be no need to edit and hope it is approved. I will consider adding the uniqueness of mine to the other question, but this will not be an answer to said question, it will be a changing of said question.

Comment: For someone who claims to be a fan of grammar, you sure are fond of misusing commas.

Comment: I was not claiming to be the best at grammar. It would make sense that the above described functionality would help me also, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Almost all major new browsers have a spell checker for example. There is no need to implement one in the WMD editor

### Firefox

[image]

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

### Internet Explorer 10

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort gone to with the screenshots; However I don't think you get the point of the request - People don't use the built in spell checkers! If the SE community is not interested in having spelling and/not grammar correctness in otherwise great answers, so be it, but if it is something that people want to address, then I think (sans a better way of dealing with it) there should be soft enforcement of correct spelling and/not grammar in the UI, as outlined in the question.

Comment: @user66001 - If some people don't use built-in spellcheckers, then that's their problem, not ours.

Comment: @JackManey - Considering the data is on our site, I understand the sentiment (and think it would be awesome if everyone went to the trouble) but cannot agree

Comment: @user66001 - Your inability to agree is not the problem of the Stack Exchange devs.

Comment: @JackManey - Wow. Okay............

Comment: @user66001 - Yes, I saw that comment the first time you posted it...

Comment: @Won't - Perhaps at least one person might agree that this is a [good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123386/how-to-deal-with-link-rot-caused-by-deletion-of-popular-off-topic-questions#comment329174_123389)