# Automatic grammar fixing in questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, editor, grammar

I would like to add automatic grammar fix when posting questions or answers.

For example, automatically capitalizes i's, when the letter is used as the word I.

This is something seriously frustrating as someone who has been spending a lot of time editing posts, the majority of which have i's which are not correctly capitalized.

Surely having the i's automatically capitalized where necessary is a simple fix to make?

Please note, that unlike [Please add a spell checker to the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor?lq=1), the request here is not for a spell checker that just mark incorrect words (like some browsers are doing already) but to have it done automatically, without me having to do anything.

Comment: As part of the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room we maintain a [Magic editor user script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js) that fixes most common mistakes and removes fluff.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I would argue that that question is not a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor as that refers to a [manual] spell checker, which people would not use anyway. This question attempts to deal with the issue of people's laziness and fix one aspect of those typos automatically. Please note that I am not advocating such a use of automatic fixes, as the answer to http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/automatic-replace-in-questions points out that automatic fixes can cause more isues than they solve.

Comment: @Greenonline sorry but can't see where you think it refers to a "manual" spell checker. Anyway by its very definition, a spell checker is automatic (i.e. scans the text to find spelling mistakes), no idea what you actually mean by "manual" spell checker.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I wasn't particularly clear - The spell checking, mentioned in the other question, _is automatic_ (be it a built-in browser checker (as referred to in the answers) or one asked to be provided for by SE (if I understand that question correctly)). However, it doesn't _actually correct_ the mistakes, it merely highlights the errors. It is then up to the user to _manually_ select/accept the auto suggestion (if there is one) or _manually_ fix the typo. However, if I understand _this question_ correctly, it refers to an _automatic_ "search and correct", or capitalisation, mechanism.

Comment: @Greenonline oh, I see now. Such a feature would be utterly horrible, if only for the fact that many programming languages are case sensitive, and "i" happens to be a very common variable name in loops. Changing it to "I" will wreak havoc on great many posts in Stack Overflow, and probably many other sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I agree wholeheartedly, auto-fixers are the work of the devil, hence my referral, in my first comment, to the answer on Meta Arduino. However, I am pointing out that this question is not a duplicate of the other, and as such, even if it is not a particularly good idea, I'm not sure if it should be marked as a "dup". It was migrated here, from Meta Raspberry Pi, in the hope of a discussion of auto-fixers. However, marking it as a "dup" has not enabled that discussion to take place (although it sort of has, with our comments). That's all I'm trying to say :-)

Comment: Thanks @Greenonline I have edited the question to reflect this better and reopened. (And downvoted due to disagreeing with such a feature)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any incorrect spelling is marked by a red squiggle under the effected word.

I am pretty sure that's not a feat of stackexchanges' web page but of your browser.

> Surely having the i's automatically capitalized where necessary is a simple fix to make?

Well there's (unfortunately and) certainly a need for something like that. There's been an [old script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3122/stack-exchange-post-editor-performing-basic-corrections-on-posts-automatically) around to support that.

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't benefit all SE sites. We on ELU would probably have to get it turned off or it might become impossible to ask questions about incorrect grammar or spellings.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, good point. Which is why this feature is (and should) be a user script that is run at an editors discretion and not automatically.