# Do not put "Know someone who can answer?" on the same level as "Your Answer"

Tags: discussion, status-declined, design

Ok before I start I just want to say that it's very minor, but I still think it's worth spending 5 minutes fixing if you guys agree with me.

Recently links to facebook, twitter and email have been added. This is fine, but I'm not a big fan of how it's displayed. Here's why:

[image]

Maybe I'm just easily annoyed and no one care about this, but I feel like sharing links shouldn't be on the same level as a title. It makes the "your answer" text a bit more hidden and clutters this whole area. Also it's set as an `h2` which is not very semantic.

So instead we could have something more in the line of this:

[image]

Comment: Agree as it is now it's too much *In my face*. It's jarring and annoying.

Comment: Those links have been there for a very long time, but they've recently been moved up so that users will actually notice it: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/436987#436987. Well, at least now we know this worked...

Comment: Added a bounty, because it's Meta

Comment: @YiJ They noticed it and they don't like it.

Comment: Also it goes down onto 2 lines when it really should be one.  Making them smaller and right aligning them would be a lot more balanced and nicer looking

Comment: +1 I'd also like to see "email, twitter or facebook" not split in two lines

Comment: Declined... [sad smiley face]

Answer (score 3):

These links were not added recently, they have existed for a while, but nobody *saw* them.

That's why I moved them up.

Note that these links only appear on 0-answer questions. So if you want the links to go away, *answer more questions*. :)

Comment: I don't have anything against having them more present, I just don't like that a sharing link and a title have the exact same styling. Getting more people to answer is great, but it shouldn't harm UX

Comment: @marcgg mmm, well, IMHO they are on the same level -- either you *have* an answer or you *know* someone who can answer. Equivalent actions that both lead to getting an answer.

Comment: Jeff, while I agree with you point I also think that the *styling* of the sharing link is wrong. I also think that @marcgg's mockup looks better.

Comment: @jeff I guess that makes sense even if I don't really agree with this. My opinion would be that actually giving the answer has a greater value than just sending it to someone that might answer.

Comment: When you put an entire sentence in bold it looks like you're shouting.  But, then again, maybe you are since it's only on 0-answer questions.  Why not use the standard *share this content* buttons from each of the providers?  I typically look for these, not text when I want to share something.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about putting icons, but I do agree that putting the entire sentence in bold feels a bit weird.

Comment: @Jeff Related but offtopic: How much traffic does facebook/twitter give SO?

Comment: I'm curious how you determine if people saw them?  I admit I've learned to ignore links like that since they've been plastered on every site on existence. They're almost spam.  But the two times a year I want to share something, I also don't need links to do it.  I already know where facebook and twitter are, and I can compose an email myself.

Comment: IMO it could be an `addthis` icon under the post vote up/down. I don't click down there because they are links and not icons and are too far from the question.

Answer (score 2):

I will admit that I never noticed the links until they became more prominent. But I do agree with @marcgg that they are a bit "in your face" and do--albeit in a minor way--detract from usability in that they add clutter to the area of the page where I want to get work done, namely, post an answer.

I'm not sure if this "share question" message is security/reputation/time trimmed, but if not, my suggestion would be to increase the prominence of the message based on:

1. Time the question has spent with zero answers.
2. Reputation of the current user.
3. Anonymous/Authenticated status of the current user.

Ultimately a minor point, but IMHO it detracts from an otherwise excellent user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Ok more space?  How about

## Know someone who can answer?  Share a link to this question via email, twits, or fb.

## Your answer

```
######################################
#                                    #
#                                    #
######################################
```