# "Know someone who can answer?" prompt wraps just one word

Tags: feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not put “Know someone who can answer?” on the same level as “Your Answer”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74201/do-not-put-know-someone-who-can-answer-on-the-same-level-as-your-answer)

Could this message be rephrased so as to not wrap?

[image: BOOOO WRAPPING]

Comment: My wife also wondered that yesterday when looking at my screen from a distance. "Oh, I thought you were on Facebook".

Comment: If this would not have been `<h2>`, things might have looked different too: [Do not put “Know someone who can answer?” on the same level as “Your Answer”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74201/do-not-put-know-someone-who-can-answer-on-the-same-level-as-your-answer). And [adding the word "referral"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink/75963#75963) would make more words wrap. Looks [much better](http://i.imgur.com/vApbQ.png). ;-)

Comment: I like [this one](http://i.imgur.com/FfgBQ.png)

Comment: Well, now it wraps 3 words. Oddly, it doesn't wrap on [ux.se]

Answer (score -1):

Shrink your font size.

Comment: Nope, not fixed. I've shrunk it and shrunk it, yet it wraps at any font size. (Opera 11 and FF 3.6 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.2, 1280x1024)

Comment: The font size, not the page render size. In Firefox you have the option to only shrink the font. Chrome (for example) doesn't give you this option, so the line continues to wrap.

Comment: Huh. I had no idea it had multiple resizing controls, each with different functionality. Well, live and learn, I guess.