# Putting mailto link also under the share button

Tags: feature-request, email, sharing

Currently for SE2 sites, when the `share` button is clicked, we get

- A shortened link for copying-and-pasting
- Three buttons to share via Google+, Facebook, and Twitter

For unanswered questions there is apparently a fourth option: that is a `mailto:` link which pre-populates the subject line and content box of the e-mail.

**Feature request**: make a "e-mail" button show up also when the `share` button is pressed, whose link is exactly the same as the e-mail link that appears for unanswered questions.

---

Notes:

1. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3919/please-add-the-ability-to-email-questions-and-answers-to-friends/102996#102996) for a description of the current behaviour.
2. I don't particularly care for this function, but [it may meet some demand](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15010/1543); and it seems strange that the e-mail functionality is built for unanswered questions and not others.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution here should be to remove the `mailto:` link from the notice below unanswered questions. The point of these options is to get the link out to as many people as possible and using e-mail seems to be an inefficient way of doing that. Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Google+ makes the link public (to a degree depending on your privacy settings of course), whereas an e-mail is private only going to the recipients you explicitly choose.

I can't see that benefit of adding the link to the sharing options outweighs the cost of making the change. It's far easier just to copy the "share" link and paste into an e-mail yourself if that's really the way you want to share the post.

Comment: "The point of these options is to get the link out to as many people as possible and using e-mail seems to be an inefficient way of doing that" -- I wouldn't be so sure.

Comment: @Jefffrey - it's targeted - unlike the other methods, but less visible (unless you have many more e-mail contacts than you do Facebook friends!).

Comment: Which is possible. Also you can send email to multiple people at the same time. I'm just saying that it doesn't hurt to have that option.

Comment: @Jefffrey - I know that - I was more referring to the fact that posting links to Facebook, Twitter & Google+ is **public** rather than private.

Comment: ... which is why they are not always appropriate. Taking the example from math.SE: having found an interesting problem I can't solve, do I want to drop a link to it into my family / friends news feeds? Vast majority won't know what the thing is about, the rest won't know how to solve it anyway. But I may happen to know a person with an expertise and interest in the particular area, and email him/her.  My point is, making public sharing the only option may lead to less publicity, not more.

Comment: Consider a mailing list of interest group. They may not have FB/G+/Twitter, but they have a common address for email. Although I agree someone may argue "then let them create the interest group on any of those social media sites", my point is there are people who still using mailing list.